# How could this that-clause come out in this sentence?

Tags: that

> A general definition of leadership is that it shows the way for others
>   either by example or by advocacy. Crucially, this definition is
>   sufficiently general **that it does not entail being in charge of those
>   who follow.**

### **that it does not entail being in charge of those who follow.**

How could this that-clause come out in this sentence? For example, because "so or such" can be followed by that-clause, I know why that-clause appears after so or such. But how could the above sentence have "that-clause"?

Comment: It means "so that".

Comment: 'Crucially, this definition is sufficiently general to not entail leaders being in charge of those who follow.' is perhaps a more common structure, but is here unwieldy. '... general enough that it does not entail being in charge of those who follow.' is very probably acceptable, so I don't see that the original is less so.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of the *so .. that* construction to *sufficiently .. that*.

I'm old-fashioned, and prefer to cast the complement of *sufficient* as a *to* infinitival; but I've seen the construction with *that* more and more often over the last 20 or 30 years, and it's a development in the direction of regularization, so I've decided I'm not going to let it me bother me.

Comment: Via the ' ... enough that'  construction?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't let that one bother me either. Life's too short.

Comment: I thought that expressions like the OP's "that it does not entail being in charge of those who follow" were acceptable in AmE as resultative content clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Acceptable, yes. For what it's worth, Google Ngrams seems to show that the infinitival versions (*sufficient(ly) ... to*, *enough to*), although still markedly more common than the constructions with content clauses, have been losing ground since just about the time I started learning English.